# Are console errors acceptable in Javascript if they do not cause problems?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm a beginner at Javascript, and I wrote some code that works perfectly, but generates a console error from time to time.
It's a coin flip simulator, where the class of the coin needs to change depending on the outcome- so it searches for the opposite outcome class name and changes it to the current outcome class name (using SetAttribute). However, sometimes you get two of the same outcomes in a row, so searching for the opposite class name returns null, and then I get an error for trying to setAttribute of null.
I could write an If statement to avoid this, but I'm wondering if that's necessary. I want to learn best practices, so please, if there's a reason to avoid console errors, let me know!

Comment: You should handle errors, yes.

Comment: Yes, you need to write a statement to avoid this. That said. welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here

Comment: Even if it works, hiding the dust under the carpet is never good. Always try to fulfill every possible case. Good code is code that handles errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console errors such as an unhandled exception indicate a problem in your code.  Sometimes the problem might turn out to be benign, but there is no way to know if its benign without studying the code.  And, by the time you have studied the code to understand the problem, it is usually one or two lines of code to avoid or handle the problem in your code.

You should add this extra code to handle the problem because if you let these benign warnings build up, then pretty soon you won't be able to notice a new warning pop up that is actually a sign of serious trouble.  Your code should be exception free precisely for this reason so when an unexpected issue shows up, you can clearly see it and both you and everyone else working on the project or testing the project knows that a warning like this is unexpected.

So, it is a good practice to clean up all warnings like this and keep your code clean and warning free.

---

Imagine you were driving your car and a warning light came on.  You take it into the mechanic and the mechanic says: "oh, that's how they designed it - the light comes on from time to time".  OK, now the warning is basically useless because you don't know when a warning is a sign of a real issue and when a warning is just some incomplete design that didn't clean things up well.  It's the same with your code.

Comment: Great analogy, makes sense. Thanks for your help.